# Entity Framework not working properly in Select clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a table with 90k records, and when I do a query with a "where" clause, in the Sql Server Profiler the sql do 300 queries with offset and fetch to return the result.
The response is very slow due the 300 queries.
What could be the cause to this behaviour?

Entity Framework 6.0

Comment: Bad queries and wrong expectations. 90K rows is tiny data, 300 concurrent queries aren't a lot BUT if you use `Skip().Take()`, each *SQL* query has to calculate and skip the initial data before it can fetch the next page. This isn't an EF issue

Comment: What kind of queries do the clients execute and *why* is paging used? It matters. *Humans* rarely go beyond the first few pages, so the effects of `OFFSET .. FETCH` wouldn't be noticed. If people often skip to the last page though, it means something's wrong with the UI or the way people use it.

Comment: If you need paging to export data, or if you need to serve API endpoints through paging, the fast option is to retrieve the IDs/PKs of the result objects and *keep them*, split them in pages, and return pages by ID. Instead of skipping you now execute an `ID in (@id1,.....,@id50)` which typically requires an index seek

Comment: Another option, if the keys are sequential, is to return the next N results after the previous ID value, eg `Where(.....).Where(order=>order.Id>lastOrderId).Take(50)`. This is *very* common in APIs. Both options come under the term `cursor pagination` and some protocols like GraphQL [explicitly support cursor pagination](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that I want 1 query to do all the result, because my query doesn't have any Skip() or Take() in code

Comment: `with offset and fetch to return the result` that means you *are* using paging, even if you do it through raw SQL, or another library in your application does.  Skip translates to `Offset` and `Take` to `Fetch`. Such queries are slow because the database has to find the N rows it has to skip. Paging isn't used by EF itself, it's something your application is doing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The query is something like this:  Select * from table where x = y order by z desc . This query doesn't need offset or fetch and the sql server does it to return 500 records

Comment: No it doesn't. SQL Server doesn't modify queries by itself. This isn't debatable. Perhaps your DbContext has an interceptor that alters the query, to prevent people from hogging resources by trying to retrieve an entire table at once?

Comment: Show your LINQ query. 300 queries can mean that you have Lazy Loading enabled, or you use EF in wrong way.

Comment: +1 for lazy loading being triggered. A `Where` clause will not trigger this to happen unless it happens after an initial query has been run (via a `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`) before the `Where` clause.  Post the actual query you are running and what some of these extra SQL queries are. Lazy Loading is easy to spot because you'll essentially see "SELECT * FROM children WHERE ParentId = 1; SELECT * from children WHERE ParentId = 2; ...."